# Rails switch boolean value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, boolean

I have have boolean value for my model 'comment' - best, it can be true of false. Here is part of my controller comments_controller.rb:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  

    before_action :find_comment, only: [:choose_best]
    
      def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :comment, :user_id, :best))
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
          format.js
        end
      end
    
      def choose_best
        @comment.choose_best!
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
      end
    
      private
    
      def find_comment
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @post_id = @post[:post_id]
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
      end
    
    end
```

Here is comment_model.rb:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :post
    
      scope :best_comments,     -> { where(best: true) }
      scope :not_best_comments, -> { where(best: false) }
    
      def choose_best!
          ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
            unless best?
              post.comments.update_all(best: false)
              update!(best: true)
            end
          end
        end
    end
```

Here is routes:

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments do
      resources :answers
      member do
        patch :choose_best
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is html:

```
<div id="post-id" data-post-id="<%= @post_id %>"> </div>
       <% if @comment.best? %>
          <h1>best</h1>
          <% else %>
          <h1>not best</h1>
          <% end %>
        <%=link_to 'Best', choose_best_post_comment_path(comment.post, comment), method: :patch, remote: true,
                   class: 'best-answer-btn btn btn-success', id: "best-comment-link-#{comment.id}"%>
</div>
```

And here is my js file for best comment:

```
<% if @comment.best? %>
$('.comments').html('<%= j render 'posts/form', post: @post.comment %>');
$('.comment-form').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
    var comment_id = $(this).parents('.comment').data('commentID');
    $('#best-comment-link-' + comment_id).hide();
})
<% end %>
```

So the problem is that when I press button 'best' - it switch boolean value for this comment but when I try to press this button to another comment - nothing changes. I tried to make def that will keep only one best comment per post (user press on 'best' button and another best comment value become false and pressed become true), so maybe the problem may be in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much better solution would be to simply add an additional foreign key column to the posts table:

```
class AddBestCommentToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_reference :posts, :best_comment, null: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :posts }
  end
end
```

```
class Post
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :best_comment, 
    class_name: 'Comment', 
    optional: true
end
```

```
def choose_best
  if @post.update(best_comment: @comment)
    head :ok
  else
    head :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Since this is a single column you don't have to worry about the edge cases where more then one comment could have the "best" flag at the same time. You can also eager load the association very efficiently.